# Canvas vs SVG (interactive application)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

What should i use for my project? In my app i have generated table, 1/2 of cells are clickable smillar to chess and each is invidual ( ID by position XY). In these cells will be circles something resembling a diode LEDs (so it will has some blurs,, gradients etc) and I put some data-*. Also i want to draw images from files as a mask for my table, resize this table, change i.e. colors for all red LEDs etc. Should i use `SVG` or `canvas`? For now i use html DOM  but it is too slow.

Comment: You should profile your application and figure out the actual performance issues before thinking about adopting another technology.

Comment: If you need a lot of interaction and are new to this kind of stuff I'd opt for SVG as programming interaction is much more DOM like with SVG, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Main interaction will be changing color/type of cells. I choose color -> click on cell -> change color. If you are saying that SVG is smillar to DOM, will it be easy to keep data in my cells? I have from 450 to 7200 cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step should be to profile your existing HTML code to find out why it's slow. A table with 7200 cells doesn't have to be slow. I had tables which are 2 MB raw HTML and the browser would render them in less than 2 seconds - five years ago.

Neither `canvas` or SVG will magically solve your performance issues for you.

Comment: I think SVG/Canvas will be better scalable on lower resolutions, as on iPhone, androids etc  than my <table> filled with images as a background of cells.

Comment: Most likely, the same 3D hardware will be used to scale the whole page.